# Is it necessary to give support for Autolayout in iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my app to Appstore, but it is rejected and the reason for rejection is "when they reviewed on iPhone 5s running iOS 7.0.3, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks they found bug". But they did not mention any bug. So, my question is - is it necessary to give a support for Auto Layout in iOS 7.0.3? and is this a only reason for rejection? 
If Autolayout is not the reason then can anyone tell what could be the reason?

Comment: No, autolayout is not required.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to include autolayout. Your problem is lying somewhere else. Apple had mentioned the reason for rejecting your app. Please confirm and let us know so that we can help if possible.

Comment: Try to communicate with them and request to provide little more details about bugs if possible. I think they will respond.

Comment: Yes.Thanks to all.will communicate with Apple and let you know ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout is not enforced in any way by Apple: you can simply opt-out as you wish.

So no, it's not the reason for the rejection. You will have to look deeper.